# Where to find my keyPassword and storePassword in google console?

Tags: react-native, gradle, apk

I'm building my React Native application and I want to deploy to the Play Store. For that I need these credentials:

```
...
signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
...
```

I'm not sure where to get the release key password from!

Comment: This is app signing config that you add while making of your `.keystore` file. Read more about app signing [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android)

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign your Apk before uploading it to play store.

On the menu bar, click `Build > Generate Signed APK`.

After going there you will get options to add your `passwords`.


Follow the instructions mentioned in link.
Signing process is completely explained in android developers docs.
[Refer Here](http://www.androiddocs.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)